# In R How to remove a precise character in a column ( in this case the " , " )that has other same character that i don't want to remove?

Tags: r

i have a dataset with some columns that have a monetized value, but considering the name of the columns and the description of them, i believe that there's an error in the representation of the numbers. i.e. (5,52,32,974)----> this is an example of the number, i believe there is a comma too many or put in the wrong position. I would like to know if it's possible to remove a certain comma in this case and came to this representation of the number, for instance 55.232.974... of $ for example. The dataset is in .csv. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correctly your data is given as a string.
Then you could use the following code:

```
a <- c("5,52,32,974", "5,52,32,974", "5,52,32,974")

b <- gsub(",", "", a)

as.numeric(b)
#[1] 55232974 55232974 55232974
```

Comment: ok thanks, but i have this problem in almost all of the columns of my dataset.

Comment: Corporate_im <- read.csv2("final_raw_sample_3_percent.csv", header = TRUE, sep = "," ). This is the imput and i would like to know if i can modify it to have those numbers like you told me. I've solved the problem doing it directly modifying the csv file but i would like to do it on R without take this shortcut of going on the csv file. Thanks

Comment: If the raw data is in the right format and while reading the data into R the decimal point is mixed up, it might help to directly specify this in the read.csv2 function (so add "dec" and specify you decimal character):
 read.csv2("final_raw_sample_3_percent.csv", header = TRUE, sep = "," , dec=",")